# Is it possible to force bash to do an in-place expansion of a variable whose value contains quotes?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, command-line-arguments

Consider the following simple function.

```
X() {
 echo "$1"
 echo "$2"
 echo "$3"
}
```

Now consider the following variable:

```
args="-H 'h1 : v1'"
```

When I run the command `X $args`, I get the following output:

```
-H
'h1
:
```

On the other hand, if I run the command `X -H 'h1 : v1'`, I get the following output:

```
-H
h1 : v1
```

Note that, in the latter case, the **quotes inside the variable's value** are correctly interpreted as delimiters.

Is it possible to modify either the declaration of the variable or the invocation with a variable to force the two outputs above to be equivalent?

Comment: Quotes that are data do not substitute for missing quotes that are syntax.

Comment: The right way to solve this is to store lists of strings _in arrays_, not strings.

Comment: That is: `args=( -H 'h1 : v1' )`, and then `X "${args[@]}"`.

Comment: Re: `X -H 'h1 : v1'` -- you aren't showing quotes inside a variable's value being honored. Where's the variable in your example?

Comment: `$2` never contained the quotes. The shell used them to see `h1 : v1` as a single word, rather than 3 separate words, then assigned that single word to the positional parameter.

Comment: To restate what chepner said in a slightly different way: When a shell starts a program (any program, written in any language), it passes an array of C strings to that program; those C strings become `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, etc in bash, or `sys.argv[0]`, `sys.argv[1]`, etc in Python, or some other equivalent in any other language. So when you run `X 'h1 : v1'`, the array in JSON syntax is `["X", "h1 : v1"]` -- note that the only quotes there are JSON syntax; the single quotes that were there as part of the shell syntax are completely gone[...]

Comment: [...] because they were consumed by the shell you entered the string `X 'h1 : v1'` into as it parsed that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what arrays are for.

```
$ args=(-H 'h1: v1')
$ printf '%s\n' "${args[@]}"
-H
h1 : v1
```

Comment: If the reason for this to be an answer is that we don't have an adequately explicit / focused duplicate to close it with, I wonder if we need to build a canonical instance for the purpose; it certainly comes up often enough.

Comment: I've lost hope that any single answer is going to be nuanced enough for many of these questions.